# Mysql migration from 5.7 to 8 leads to a string and integer comparison issues in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Mysql migration from 5.7 to 8 leads to a string and integer comparison issues in Stored Procedure.

for eg :

```
if @tran <>0 or @tran <> '' then
    set Message = 'SUCCESS';
else
    set Message = 'FAIL in tran';
    rollback;
end if;
```

The @tran will have either "success" or 0   ( integer zero )

While it returns success it leads to error - 1292Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'SUCCESS'

Kindly suggest what to do without changing the SPS because same syntax is used in many places which takes huge time to change.

Comment: The error you're encountering is due to the fact that in MySQL 8, the SQL mode TRADITIONAL is enabled by default, which is more strict about data type conversions. In your case, comparing a string ('SUCCESS') to an integer (0) triggers the error. you can set it globally for the MySQL server by modifying the configuration to be like this `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`. For further info regarding `sql_mode`, you can check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html